# WooCommerce email routed based on product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are trying to set up a function to route emails to different emails depending on if the order contains a product in Category A, or Category B, or both.

I was able to get the email to go through without the conditions, but once we added the category conditions nothing was being sent.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function send_custom_order_email( $order_id ) {
    // get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // set up the email recipients
    $product_categories = array();
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'slugs') );
        if ( in_array( 'category-a', $product_categories ) ) {
            $recipient = 'test1@email.com';
            break;
        } elseif ( in_array( 'category-b', $product_categories ) ) {
            $recipient = 'test2@email.com';
            break;
        } else {
            $recipient = 'backup@email.com';
        }
    }
    $subject = "New order #" . $order_id . " has been received";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    // set up the email body
    $message = '<p>Dear ' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . ',</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Thank you for placing an order with us. Your order number is ' . $order_id . '.</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Your order details:</p>';
    $message .= '<ul>';
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product_name = $item->get_name();
        $product_qty = $item->get_quantity();
        $product_total = $item->get_total();
        $message .= '<li>' . $product_name . ' x ' . $product_qty . ' - ' . wc_price( $product_total ) . '</li>';
    }
    $message .= '</ul>';
    // send the email
    $sent = wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers );
    if($sent) {\n        error_log("Email sent to $recipient for order #$order_id");
    } else {
        error_log("Error sending email for order #$order_id");
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_custom_order_email', 10, 1 );
```